# TLS Error: Upgrading Ubuntu to 22.04 causes Flutter Installation/Upgrade Failure

Tags: linux, flutter, ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04

After upgrading Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04, encountered an error while attempting to install or upgrade Flutter. The specific error message received is as follows:

[image: [Error message here]]

Having investigated the issue by referring to various links and forums, and it appears that there might be a network or firewall-related problem causing this error. However, its have confirmed that the firewall is turned off and the network connectivity is functioning properly.

Would appreciate any guidance or suggestions you may have regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing the issue because there is no SSL certificate found in your system which can be resolved by running the below command:

```
sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh
```

The above command will update SSL certificate in your system then you can run the flutter doctor command to complete the installation of your flutter.